# Why do we need specific classes to work with Request and Response?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, request, response

I want to understand why we need specific classes to work with Request and Response. What's wrong with global variables like $_POST, $_GET, etc...
Why is better and what's the problems it solves?

edit 1:
Thank you, I know about PSRs. But the real question why is it bad?
I don't think that the using $_GET, $_POST, etc is bad. Because why we would change its values?

Comment: It is not the same things. In example $_GET array contains only parameters, no cookies, headers, etc. Request class has much more information, and often this classes implements PSR-7 standard (https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/)

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I just gave an example. But there's no problem actually to get cookies, header with global variables too.

Comment: The real question is "Do you need to use a framework for you project?" Looking at your (broad and off-topic) question I think not (and SO is not a Forum on where to discuss broad arguments or about what you can simply find in the "tool's" documentation). To make precise and on-topic questions (specially after 29 months of membership) I strongly encourage you to read the whole [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) paying special attention to the Asking Section.

Comment: @gp_sflover of course, I need framework, It's too ambiguous, too start writing without framework, so I just thought, maybe will shine my eyes on how Request and Response working inside that frameworks, I have written my own implementations of those, but didn't really understand what problems they really solve, I think it's because I make very easy sites, which are bunch of some CRUD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html) :

*The Request class is an object-oriented representation of the HTTP request message. With it, you have all the request information at your fingertips*

and

*As a bonus, the Request class does a lot of work in the background that you'll never need to worry about. For example, the isSecure() method checks the three different values in PHP that can indicate whether or not the user is connecting via a secured connection*

Comment: Yes, I understand first part, thank you. But all is it do, is just some checking in background? I have very little experience, about an  year, and I didn't understand why we really need an abstraction of Request. So only because there's some real checkings and it helps us to create some objecsts like UploadedFile, etc?

Comment: This adds a bunch of methods to use such as isPost, allows you to restrict your routes to certain methods only, creates objects like you said, and more. Basically it's doing what a Framework does : simplifying the workflow without having you to do the same things twice.